# TypeError: inspect(...).addField is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
    var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#f03824')
    .setTitle('Evaluated')
    .addField(`To Eval`, `\`\`\`${command}\`\`\``)
    .addField('Evaled', `\`\`\`js\n${inspect(evaled, { depth: 0})}\`\`\``
    .addField(`Type Of`, `\`\`\`${typeof(evaled)}\`\`\``))
        message.channel.send(embed)
```

How do i fix this error?
TypeError: inspect(...).addField is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing parentheses `)` at the end of the line

```js
.addField('Evaled', `\`\`\`js\n${inspect(evaled, { depth: 0})}\`\`\``
```

Add it and it should work:

```js
.addField('Evaled', `\`\`\`js\n${inspect(evaled, { depth: 0})}\`\`\``)
```